# Spectrum of unit hyperspheres in large dimensions

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Each eigenvalue of $\mathbb{S}^n$ is $k(k+n-2)$ with multiplicity $((n^2-3n+2)+ 2(n-1)k)\binom{n+k-3}{k}$. I would like to confirm that result in using the Weyl's law (see [Spectral Geometry in Non-standard
Domains](https://www.fields.utoronto.ca/programs/scientific/14-15/summer-research14/mini-conf/SpectralGeometryReport.pdf)
), i.e. $$N(\lambda) \sim \frac{\omega_n \text{Vol}(\mathbb{S}^n) \lambda^{\frac{n}{2}}}{(2 \pi)^n},$$ which the volume of an unit hypersphere is $\omega_n=\frac{\pi^\frac{n}{2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+1)}$ and also $\text{Vol}(\mathbb{S}^n)=\frac{\pi^\frac{n=1}{2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n+1}{2}+1)}$. In using the identity $\Gamma(x)=\frac{2^{x-1}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(\frac{x}{2}) \Gamma(\frac{x+1}{2})$, we obtain that $$\omega_n \text{Vol}(\mathbb{S}^n) = \frac{2^ {n+1}\pi^{\frac{4n+1}{2}}}{(n+1)!},$$ and then $$\frac{\omega_n \text{Vol}(\mathbb{S}^n) \lambda_k^{\frac{n}{2}}}{(2 \pi)^n}=\frac{2 \pi^{\frac{2n+1}{2}} (k(k+n-2))^{\frac{n}{2}}}{(n+1)!}.$$ Furthermore, when we consider the multiplicity of $\lambda=\lambda_k$, we obtain that $$N(\lambda_k)= \sum_{j=0}^k ((n^2-3n+2)+ 2(n-1)j)\binom{n+j-3}{j} = (k+1) (2 k+n-1) \binom{k+n-2}{k+1}.$$ Could anyone be able to verify me the W.L with this result. I tried many time to solve it, but I didn't succeed.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you try [Stirling's_approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) ?

Comment: Haha, yes, I just finished watching the problem with this identity. No, it doesn't work @user1952009.

Comment: I think I have a mistake. The problem of the hypersphere is in the attached document, and the answers aren't the same.

Comment: Your expression for $\omega_n \text{Vol}_n$ is wrong. We have $\frac{\omega_n \text{Vol}_n}{(2\pi)^n} = \frac{2}{(n+1)!}$.